# Symfony 3 using a macro in a macro?

Tags: symfony, macros, twig

i want to use a macro in a macro. But how is this working?

1. macro in my twig:

   ```
       {% import _self as formSubmacros %}

   {% macro printSubcategoriesRow(SubcategoriesForm) %}
       <div class="the content of the subcatecories">

       </div>
   {% endmacro %}
   ```
2. macro i write just under the first and here i want to get the 1 macro in:

   ```
       {% import _self as formMacros %}

   {% macro printCategoriesRow(CategoriesForm) %}
       <div class="the content of the categories with the macro subcategories">



               {% for SubcategoriesForm in CategoriesForm.subcategories %}
                   {{ formSubmacros.printSubcategoriesRow(SubcategoriesForm) }}
               {% endfor %}



       </div>
   {% endmacro %}
   ```

But this is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the `import` into your macro, to get the proper scope. If this is not working, please provide the error message

Comment: It works. But I was not sure, because I can not get my class via JavaScript. Must the JavaScript in the imported macro too?

Comment: Sorry - no its fine. Works well ;-)